# How to match a value in json file with PHP

Tags: php

I am saving data in JSON file for retrieving after redirect. If I check if the value matches in the json array, I always get false and something must be wrong, but I cannot figure it out. How can I the object with the specific `SSL_SESSION_ID`

Here's my json

```
[
    {
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN": "John,Doe,12345678912",
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_G": "JOHN",
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_S": "DOE",
        "SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY": "SUCCESS",
        "SSL_SESSION_ID": "365cb4834f9d7b3d53a3c8b2eba55a49d5cac0112994fff95c690b9079d810af"
    },
    {
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN": "John,Doe,12345678912",
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_G": "JOHN",
        "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_S": "DOE",
        "SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY": "SUCCESS",
        "SSL_SESSION_ID": "e7bd2b6cd3db89e2d6fad5e810652f2ae087965e64b565ec8933b1a67120b0ac"
    }
]
```

Here's my PHP script, which always returns `It doesn't match`

```
            $sslData     = Storage::disk('private')->get('ssl_login.json');
            $decodedData = json_decode($sslData, true);
            foreach ($decodedData as $key => $items) {

                if ($items['SSL_SESSION_ID'] === $SSL_SESSION_ID) {
                    dd("It matches");


                } else {
                    dd("It doesn't match");

                }
            }
```

Comment: What does `$SSL_SESSION_ID` contain and where do you set it? Also, if the `$SSL_SESSION_ID` doesn't match with the first value, you're currently stopping the script and outputting the error message.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $SSL_SESSION_ID comes from request and I am getting it like this:    $SSL_SESSION_ID    = Request::get('SSL_SESSION_ID');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script will *always* end after the first iteration, since you're using `dd()` regardless if it was a match or not and you will always get the "no-match"-message if the first iteration isn't a match.

You should iterate through all the items and then see if there was a match or not:

```
$match = null;
foreach ($decodedData as $key => $items) {
    if ($items['SSL_SESSION_ID'] === $SSL_SESSION_ID) {
        $match = $items;
        // We found a match so let's break the loop
        break;
    }
}

if (!$match) {
    dd('No match found');
}

dd('Match found');
```

That will also save the matching item in the `$match` variable if you need to use the data somehow.